# CDC. cannot delete from table because it does not have a replica identity and publishes deletes

Tags: postgresql, change-data-capture

Setting up the Change Data Capture with Postgresql.
Enabled replica for one table:
alter table TABLE_NAME REPLICA IDENTITY FULL;

When trying to delete a record from a completely different table, we get an error.

```
ERROR:  cannot delete from table TABLE_NAME because it does not 
        have a replica identity and publishes deletes

HINT:  To enable deleting from the table, set REPLICA IDENTITY 
       using ALTER TABLE.
```

Even there is to disable replication at the level of all databases, the error remains.
Please tell me how to deal with this problem? Maybe there is a link to the relevant article? Internet search did not return any results.

Comment: Only one table is mentioned,  What is the "completely different" table completely different from?

Comment: replication was enabled on table 1.
When deleting a record from table 2, it swears at table 3, where the outer key refers to table 2. CONSTRAINT ON DELETE CASCADE

all tables in one schema. At the same time, in other schemes, everything works without changes.

Comment: Sounds like you have a trigger which is cascading deletes.  Did you set REPLICA IDENTITY FULL for the table the error is being thrown on (not the one the initial delete is on)?

Comment: No, I made a REPLICA IDENTITY FULL only for table 1. And I delete it from table 2 from the same schema. Also swears on table 3 as it is deleted through cascade removal. Alternatively, all tables can be REPLICA IDENTITY FULL  enabled. But I think there is a better solution. Tembolee if at me for example there will be one thousand tables.